# Applying manual AES encryption instead of using HTTPS

Tags: security, ssl, https, webserver, aes

Due to a couple of issues with my host, I'm unable to use a SSL-certificate on my server (I'm not ready to change provider just yet), and can't therefore use HTTPS. This server will communicate with a couple of client-computers and will transfer data that's somewhat secret.

**Would it be reasonable to simply use AES encryption** (encryption on client before sending, decryption on server before processing) **instead of HTTPS?**

Comment: Yeah id say pretty simple. You might have to configure a tunnel on the client machines though. If that's ok, I can give an explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on your deployment environment.

Replacing SSL/TLS (and HTTPS) with your own encryption protocol for use by a web browser is always a bad idea, since it relies on JavaScript code delivered insecurely (for details, see [this question on Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/24433/2435), for example).

If the client isn't a web browser, you have more options available. In particular, you can implement message-level security instead of transport-level security (which is what HTTPS uses).

There are a number of attempts to standardise message-level security with HTTP. For example:

- [HTTPsec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPsec) had a public specification ([still available on WebArchive](http://web.archive.org/web/20100726024942/http://www.httpsec.org/1.0/)), but a commercial implementation. I'm not sure whether this has been widely reviewed.
- [WS-Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security), oriented towards the world of SOAP.

Perhaps more simply, if you want to re-use existing tools, you could use S/MIME or PGP (in the same way as you would for e-mails) to encrypt the HTTP message entities. Unlike HTTPS, this won't protect the URL or the HTTP headers, but this might be enough if you don't put any sensitive data there.

The further down you go with "raw encryption" yourself (using AES directly, for example), the more likely you'll have to implement other aspects of security manually (typically, verifying the remote party's identity and dealing with the problem of pre-sharing the keys).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's highly appreciated. The client itself is not a web browser, but rather a normal application (Java).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small list of clients that don't change often, you could implement your own SSL-Tunnel using SSH. On the clients do a;

```
ssh -D 4444 nulluser@example.com -N
```

where `nulluser` has no shell or file access on `example.com`.

Then add a foxyproxy whitelist setting - so that for `example.com` the client browsers use the `localhost:4040` proxy.

It's a hack, it's totally unscalable, but it would work as I say for a small, static number of clients, and it has the advantage of not reinventing any wheels while being totally secure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The number of clients will sadly be variating (though mostly per year), hopefully I will have ~100 clients..